# Camunda tests stop working after asyncBefore flag set to true for bpmn start event

Tags: java, asynchronous, junit, bpmn, camunda

Using tests from official Camunda Github repo: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-assert

`examples` folder contains a few bpmn files and tests, by default all works fine, all tests successfully passed, but when I set flag `Asynchronous Before` for `Start event` for any `bpmn` - all asserts start failing.

What is the right way to write tests when `bpmn` start event executed in `async` fashion?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid that automatic background threads spoil your test control, the jobExecutor is normally turned off in unit tests.

If you have an async continuation, you will have to execute the job manually by running `execute(job())` after starting the process.